# Как сформировтаь строковое представление даты

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Доброго всем кодинга. Раньше в Delphi 4, 5 и 7 всё было понятно. Теперь есть XE, делаю это (переменная - "e", в ней переименовываются числовые значения месяцев в слова):

```
Label2.Caption := e+' г. '+FormatDateTime('DDD.', Date);
```

Получаю это:

```
.июля 2014г. Чт 10
```

А раньше Delphi 7 компилировал так:

```
10 июля 2014 г. Чт.
```

---

Вопрос знатокам - почему всё поменялось в Delphi XE? Как тут быть? Как расставить знаки?
Опять идти учиться составлению строковых переменных?

Answer (score 3):

А какая у вас текущая локаль? Может быть, иврит или арабский?

Comment: @VladD Ага! Вот почему у меня менюшка в права стала жаться!!!

Comment: @I_CaR: Хотя, может быть и [это](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7). Или [это](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-the-display-language).

Comment: А при чём тут Windows, осмелюсь спросить?  
ведь Delphi 7 нормально компилирует эту переменную. У меня и Delphi 7 и Delphi XE работают.  
Да и по умолчанию, родная - аглицкая(США) + Русская.  
Итого две.

Comment: @I_CaR: Хм. Посмотрите обновлённый предыдущий комментарий. Где-то должна затесаться right-to-left-локаль.

А Delphi в новой версии при сложении строк начал учитывать локаль. Или у вас просто она поменялась. У вас давно меню уехало вправо?

Comment: Спасибо @VladD, уже читаю, но мне всё-таки кажется, что собака зарыта в Delphi XE... Чую по запаху.

Comment: @I_CaR: но смену локали вы отыскали?

Comment: @VladD нет.
Перешёл опять на Delphi 7

Comment: @I_CaR: Всё же, вы бы посмотрели на текущую локаль того потока, в котором поведение функции неправильно. Ну да ладно.

Comment: @Saidolim: Является-является. Описанное автором поведение — правильное поведение для RTL-локали. Следовательно, его проблема в локали.

Answer (score 0):

Все прекрасно работает. Проверил на XE4. Точку в формате возьмите в кавычки. В справке на функцию `FormatDateTime` нет символа [.] для формата.

```
Label2.Caption := FormatDateTime('DDD"."', Date);
```

Comment: А с менюшкой как быть?